# Is it possible to create a hierarchy of annotations with UIMA?

Tags: uima

I would like to be able to get a common feature from different annotation types. Is it possible to create sub-classes of the annotations and then get them by the super-class?

This is the way I am doing it at the moment but I would like to be able to get a general super-class of annotation rather than a specific one.

```java
TypeSystem typeSystem = jcas.getTypeSystem();
Type type = typeSystem.getType("com.example.SpecificAnnotation");
AnnotationIndex<Annotation> annotationIndex = jcas.getAnnotationIndex(type);
Annotation annotation = annotationIndex.iterator().next();
String value = annotation.getFeatureValueAsString(type.getFeatureByBaseName("value"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an annotation type X with the common features. Then you can create additional annotation types which inherit from your type X instead of inheriting from Annotation.

Comment: just like you would do with a Java class, inheriting from another.

Comment: Kind of. Mind that you should not actually inherit from the JCas Java class yourself (if you use JCas). You should define the type in your type system descriptor to inherit from another type. If you generate JCas classes from these types, they will also inherit from each other.